# How to correctly get the twig value

Tags: 8, theming

I have the following response using `kint`. How can I correctly get the value of the title.

I tried `stream.node_title[0]['#context'].output` but getting `null` result.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it should be

```
{{ stream.node_title[0][0]['#context'].output }}
```

You can get the other two with

```
{{ stream.node_title[0][1]['#context'].output }}
{{ stream.node_title[0][2]['#context'].output }}
```

But obviously this would be hard coded. To make all of this dynamic, you can loop.

```
{% for title in stream.node_title[0] %}
    {{ title['#context'].output }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response @No Sssweat. Will try that now.

Comment: wow perfect! I think the reason why there's an additional `[0]`, its because theres an array. Thank you very much!